# Good Terminal Manager for Windows 7 with Fullscreen mode

Tags: windows, ssh, terminal

I need a good terminal manager for Windows with ssh support that will have a fullscreen terminal mode so that i can switch to fullscreen and see only the terminal content without any toolbars etc.

I've tried Putty Connection Manager and mRemoteNG but they don't have this mode or am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by terminal manager, in particular compared to plain PuTTY, which does have a fullscreen mode?

Comment: @ak2 software like Putty Connection Manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putty has Alt+Enter shortcut for that.

Comment: yes but it doesn't work inside Putty Connection Manager